# Error al acceder a url odata Microsoft dynamics 365

Tags: genexus

Al intentar acceder con la herramienta External Data Store Service Import a la URL para recuperar las entidades de Microsoft Dynamics 365 devuelve el error "The remote server returned an error: (401) Unathorized" con las credenciales de acceso correctas.

Si accedo desde el navegador a esta misma URL accede correctamente y devuelve el xml con las entidades.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]